# Update Multiple Database Rows With Multiple Dynamic Checkboxes

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have a web app that dynamically creates a table of people that have been booked to work at an event with checkboxes to show which days.

[image: Screenshot One]
I need to update the database to save the state of the checkboxes against each person. The database structure looks like this:

[image: Screenshot Two]

I have been looking around the web trying to work out how to loop through the table and update the relevant rows in the database but to no avail.

Comment: You have to show a little bit of code to show us what you've tried, what's not working, etc...  Also, don't use comma delimited strings in your data.  Bad design.  Use separate columns.

Comment: Without seeing the `html` for the form, it's not possible to provide an answer. It entirely depends on how the form processes the data.

Comment: Or even better, do a second table where you refer to the id and save every day for itself, so it is easier to delete and update/insert new days.

Comment: I ended up moving away from this project but I've started working on it again. However I like @KevinKendzia idea, simple and elegent. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to implement the solution suggested by Kevin in the comments above.

> ... do a second table where you refer to the id and save every day for itself, so it is easier to delete and update/insert new days.